# "NameError: uninitialized constant" when fake exists in same file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say I have:

**app/models/food/fruit.rb:**

```
module Food
  class Fruit
    class_attribute :field_mapping
    self.field_mapping = MyOrg::Trees::Details.field_mapping
    # other things including:
    
  end
end
```

In local/development mode, I can open a console and do/get this:

```
rails console
[1] pry(main)> Food::Fruit
NameError: uninitialized constant MyOrg::Trees::Details
```

`MyOrg::Trees::Details` will eventually be defined via a gem, but until then I want to fake it by adding the following to the top of the same file; why isn't this doing the trick?

```
module MyOrg
  module Trees
    class Details
      def field_mapping
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Note: when I paste the above into a local/development console, I can then successfully do this:

```
[2] pry(main)> MyOrg::Trees::Details.new.field_mapping
=> nil
```

Comment: Thanks. I've simplified the question.

Answer (score 0):

When I added the above fake, I accidentally started trying to reference it to test what I was doing...

```
rails console
[1] pry(main)> MyOrg::Trees::Details
NameError: uninitialized constant MyOrg::Trees::Details
```

...but I should have called `Food::Fruit` as before, and I would have isolated the issue...

```
rails console
[1] pry(main)> Food::Fruit                                                      
NoMethodError: undefined method `field_mapping' for MyOrg::Trees::Details:Class
```

...ah, I need to make it a class method...

```
module MyOrg
  module Trees
    class Details
      def self.field_mapping
      end
    end
  end
end
```

...and then...

```
rails console
[1] pry(main)> Food::Fruit
NoMethodError: undefined method `values' for nil:NilClass
```

So, I appeased the undefined method error, and now have a new problem, which is that further down the original code there is actually another reference to field_mapping (`field_mapping.values`) which now has to be appeased...

```
module MyOrg
  module Trees
    class Details
      def self.field_mapping
        {}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

...and now...

```
rails console
[1] pry(main)> Food::Fruit
=> Food::Fruit
```